# CodeIgniter Custom URI Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, permalinks

I want to create custom permalinks on CodeIgniter, actually i bought the script but the developer left that project due to some indifference. so now the problem is i have no idea how to change permalinks on that script. The main permalinks issue is when i search anything on searchbar i get this url:

> domain.com/?s=xxxxx%20yyyyy

instead of that i want this url structure:

> domain.com/search/xxxxxx-yyyyy/

**application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller']    = "music";

$route['404_override']          = '';

$route['search/(:any)']         = "music/index/$0/$1/$2";

$route['search/music/(:any)']   = "music/$1";
```

Comment: you have to put this $route variables in route.php file not in config.php

Comment: Can you show us your search form ??

Comment: <form method="GET" action=""><div class="page-content inset" style="margin:auto;"> <div class="row">               
                 <div class="col-md-12 well"> <div class="input-group input-group" style="width:100%">  <input type="search" required class="form-control s" id="s2" name="s" placeholder="<?php echo ___("label_listen"); ?>" value="">
                         <span class="input-group-btn">
                             <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSearch" type="submit"><?php echo ___("label_search"); ?> <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> </span>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are asking for is **not possible (directly)**.
Assuming your form to be,

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search music..." />
</form>
```

And since the method is `GET` the default functionality says to add the parameter in the URL as query string.

As the specifications ([RFC1866](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt), page 46; [HTML 4.x](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) section 17.13.3) state:

> If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes the value of action, appends a `?' to it, then appends the form data set, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.

So, basically what you can do here is apply a **hack** to this. **Redirect** the user to the required URL when the search is applied. 
Here's how you can go,

**Controller** *(controllers/music.php)*

```
<?php
class Music extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('xyz_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->input->get('s'))
        {
             $s = $this->input->get('s');
             redirect('/search/'$s);
        }

        $this->load->view('home.php');
    }


    public function search()
    {
        $s = $this->uri->segment(2);

        /*
        Now you got your search parameter.
        Search in your models and display the results.
       */

       $data['search_results'] = $this->xyz_model->get_search($s);
       $this->load->view('search_results.php', $data);
    }
}
```